# javascript string expression as if condition

Tags: javascript

I am building a string which is to be evaluated as if condition, like

```
if (location_val.length == 1) {
    condition = condition + " v.location === '" + location_val + "' &&";
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < location_val.length; i++) {
        condition = condition + " v.location === '" + location_val[i] + "' && ";
    }
}
```

but javascript evaluates the variable if it is not null, undefined, 0 or empty string, how to evaluate string as expression? I am using condition variable as follows, but it always returns true because of the above reason.

```
  if(condition)
```

Comment: with eval ...eventually

Comment: Yeah, dont do that. Build the expression properly - evaluating a string is just a bad idea.

Comment: Congrats - you picked the *worst possible solution*. :(

Comment: sorry @Jamiec, Actually I wanted to vote it, but clicked the wrong button

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In JavaScript there's the eval function. You can use it to evaluate a string as an expression.

```
eval('3 + 2 === 5') //true
```

I would recommend you to rethink your solution, though, since working with strings as expressions when you could solve your problem differently, is really error prone and literally the worst practise.

Also use === instead of == 
(=== works as you'd expect == to work, == doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

Build your expression properly - not using string concatenation, its something like this:

```
var condition = (location_val.length == 1 && v.location == location_val)
                 || (location_val.every(function(loc){ return v.location === loc; } );

if(condition) {
   ....
}
```

I suspect there is more to this (you have `&&` at the end of both strings) but the same applies to everything else. Boolean's can be combined in parts

```
var condition1 = (location_val.length == 1 && v.location == location_val)
                  || (location_val.every(function(loc){ return v.location === loc; } );
var condition2 = ...
var condition3 = ...

if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
   ....
}
```